# ElasticSearch high number of index causes OOM

Tags: python, indexing, elasticsearch

I've been struggling with this problem for quite a bit and now I decided to post a question on the topic to seek for some advice.

I'm testing the environment for indexing a big number of data over time. Basically everyday I'll index logs and associated documents from various websites.

I want to have one index per website to have a better logical division and to be able to filter the queries and have faster responses.

I foresee a traffic of ~1Gb of data per day per index.

I'm testing the environment on an AWS instance with 2x80Gb SSDs, CPU vendor: Intel, CPU model: Xeon (2500 MHz), CPU total logical cores: 8

I have 1 node, x indexes and 1 shard per index (for the test environment) and pushing documents taken from wikipedia articles, randomly distributing them on 200 indexes or more.

I'm indexing documents form a Queue, with a single client at the rate of about 200/s. This is just for testing. When I'll be able to fix the OOM issue, I'll increase the number of clients and the number of nodes.

I have I tried with 500k docs and 200 indexes and it is fine, if  I try with 500k and 300 indexes, it throws the hated OOM error exception. Also 1m documents and 100 indexes throws back an OOM error. 
I'm running now tests with 1m documents and 200 indexes.

I tried changing the shard number, and I also tried to play with these parameters 
index.merge.policy.max_merged_segment: 2g 
 index.merge.policy.segments_per_tier:  [ I tried 5 (and reduced the max number too) - 25] 
 index.merge.policy.max_merge_at_once: 8

My settings are (retrieved with the /_nodes/settings,os,process,jvm?pretty command)

```
{ 
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch", 
  "nodes" : { 
    "QBk8YzISQPu-VVMnKvhEmQ" : { 
      "name" : "", 
      "transport_address" : "", 
      "host" : "", 
      "ip" : "", 
      "version" : "1.1.0", 
      "build" : "2181e11", 
      "http_address" : "", 
      "settings" : { 
        "path" : { 
          "data" : "/mnt/db/se_data/elasticsearch/", 
          "logs" : "/mnt/db/searchengines/elasticsearch-1.1.0/logs", 
          "home" : "/mnt/db/searchengines/elasticsearch-1.1.0" 
        }, 
        "cluster" : { 
          "name" : "elasticsearch" 
        }, 
        "index" : { 
          "number_of_shards" : "1" 
        }, 
        "foreground" : "yes", 
        "name" : "", 
        "max-open-files" : "true" 
      }, 
      "os" : { 
        "refresh_interval" : 1000, 
        "available_processors" : 8, 
        "cpu" : { 
          "vendor" : "Intel", 
          "model" : "Xeon", 
          "mhz" : 2500, 
          "total_cores" : 8, 
          "total_sockets" : 8, 
          "cores_per_socket" : 32, 
          "cache_size_in_bytes" : 25600 
        }, 
        "mem" : { 
          "total_in_bytes" : 31502180352 
        }, 
        "swap" : { 
          "total_in_bytes" : 3071995904 
        } 
      }, 
      "process" : { 
        "refresh_interval" : 1000, 
        "id" : 20155, 
        "max_file_descriptors" : 64000, 
        "mlockall" : false 
      }, 
      "jvm" : { 
        "pid" : 20155, 
        "version" : "1.7.0_51", 
        "vm_name" : "Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM", 
        "vm_version" : "24.51-b03", 
        "vm_vendor" : "Oracle Corporation", 
        "start_time" : 1398962098305, 
        "mem" : { 
          "heap_init_in_bytes" : 268435456, 
          "heap_max_in_bytes" : 10667687936, 
          "non_heap_init_in_bytes" : 24313856, 
          "non_heap_max_in_bytes" : 136314880, 
          "direct_max_in_bytes" : 10667687936 
        }, 
        "gc_collectors" : [ "ParNew", "ConcurrentMarkSweep" ], 
        "memory_pools" : [ "Code Cache", "Par Eden Space", "Par Survivor Space", "CMS Old Gen", "CMS Perm Gen" ] 
      } 
    } 
  } 
}
```

Here are the JVM settings: 
`-Xms256m -Xmx10g -Xss256k -Djava.awt.headless=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -Delasticsearch -Des.foreground=yes`

max numbers of file open is set to 65k (this was the previous issue i had.. the number of allowed open files was only 4k)

Checking the memory consumption with bigdesk, I see the Heap Memory committed/used grows constantly while reaching the crash-point. I think that is causing the OOM error even though it crashes when the consumption reaches ~4-6Gb towards a max allocated java heap of 10Gb.

Could it be a GC problem? Should I follow the settings from this article to tune it?

If I insert a flush() command every, say, 10k inserted documents on any index, could it help reducing the memory usage?

Is the number of indexes too high? Should I change the approach? Put more logs coming from different websites in a single index seem to be the most plausible solution, is it?

PS: I'm using and a python script to test the environment, with the elasticsearch for python module (should I use pyelasticsearch instead? It should be just a feature-richer module, right?).

Let me know if you need more info. 
Thank you for your time!

EDIT:
The stacktrace from the ES log file is the following - trying to load 500k documents on 300 index.

```
[2014-05-01 00:16:49,526][INFO ][node                     ] [Captain Wings] stopping ...
[2014-05-01 00:16:49,767][WARN ][index.shard.service      ] [Captain Wings] [index_220][0] Failed to perform scheduled engine refresh
org.elasticsearch.index.engine.RefreshFailedEngineException: [index_220][0] Refresh failed
    at org.elasticsearch.index.engine.internal.InternalEngine.refresh(InternalEngine.java:725)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.service.InternalIndexShard.refresh(InternalIndexShard.java:469)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.service.InternalIndexShard$EngineRefresher$1.run(InternalIndexShard.java:920)
    [...]
    at org.apache.lucene.codecs.compressing.CompressingStoredFieldsWriter.close(CompressingStoredFieldsWriter.java:138)
    [...]
    ... 5 more
    Suppressed: java.io.FileNotFoundException: _75.fdx
        at org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory.fileLength(FSDirectory.java:261)
        at org.apache.lucene.store.FilterDirectory.fileLength(FilterDirectory.java:63)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.store.Store$StoreIndexOutput.close(Store.java:611)
        at org.apache.lucene.codecs.compressing.CompressingStoredFieldsIndexWriter.close(CompressingStoredFieldsIndexWriter.java:205)
        ... 24 more
[2014-05-01 00:16:49,804][WARN ][index.merge.scheduler    ] [Captain Wings] [index_65][0] failed to merge
java.io.FileNotFoundException: _7n_es090_0.tim
    at org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory.fileLength(FSDirectory.java:261)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.FilterDirectory.fileLength(FilterDirectory.java:63)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.store.Store$StoreIndexOutput.close(Store.java:611)
    at org.apache.lucene.util.IOUtils.closeWhileHandlingException(IOUtils.java:81)
    at org.apache.lucene.codecs.BlockTreeTermsWriter.close(BlockTreeTermsWriter.java:1140)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.codec.postingsformat.BloomFilterPostingsFormat$BloomFilteredFieldsConsumer.close(BloomFilterPostingsFormat.java:371)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.codec.postingsformat.Elasticsearch090PostingsFormat$1.close(Elasticsearch090PostingsFormat.java:61)
    at org.apache.lucene.codecs.perfield.PerFieldPostingsFormat$FieldsConsumerAndSuffix.close(PerFieldPostingsFormat.java:86)
    at org.apache.lucene.util.IOUtils.close(IOUtils.java:163)
    at org.apache.lucene.codecs.perfield.PerFieldPostingsFormat$FieldsWriter.close(PerFieldPostingsFormat.java:154)
    at org.apache.lucene.util.IOUtils.close(IOUtils.java:140)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentMerger.mergeTerms(SegmentMerger.java:389)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentMerger.merge(SegmentMerger.java:106)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.mergeMiddle(IndexWriter.java:4119)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.merge(IndexWriter.java:3716)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.TrackingSerialMergeScheduler.merge(TrackingSerialMergeScheduler.java:122)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.merge.scheduler.SerialMergeSchedulerProvider$CustomSerialMergeScheduler.merge(SerialMergeSchedulerProvider.java:89)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.merge.EnableMergeScheduler.merge(EnableMergeScheduler.java:71)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.maybeMerge(IndexWriter.java:1936)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.maybeMerge(IndexWriter.java:1930)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.merge.Merges.maybeMerge(Merges.java:47)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.engine.internal.InternalEngine.maybeMerge(InternalEngine.java:926)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.service.InternalIndexShard$EngineMerger$1.run(InternalIndexShard.java:966)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
    Suppressed: java.io.FileNotFoundException: _7n_es090_0.tip
        ... 26 more
    Suppressed: java.io.FileNotFoundException: _7n_es090_0.doc
        at org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory.fileLength(FSDirectory.java:261)
        at org.apache.lucene.store.FilterDirectory.fileLength(FilterDirectory.java:63)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.store.Store$StoreIndexOutput.close(Store.java:611)
        at org.apache.lucene.util.IOUtils.close(IOUtils.java:140)
        at org.apache.lucene.codecs.lucene41.Lucene41PostingsWriter.close(Lucene41PostingsWriter.java:587)
        ... 23 more
        Suppressed: java.io.FileNotFoundException: _7n_es090_0.pos
            ... 28 more
[2014-05-01 00:16:49,807][WARN ][index.engine.internal    ] [Captain Wings] [index_65][0] failed engine
org.apache.lucene.index.MergePolicy$MergeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: _7n_es090_0.tim
    at org.elasticsearch.index.merge.scheduler.SerialMergeSchedulerProvider$CustomSerialMergeScheduler.merge(SerialMergeSchedulerProvider.java:92)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.merge.EnableMergeScheduler.merge(EnableMergeScheduler.java:71)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.maybeMerge(IndexWriter.java:1936)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.maybeMerge(IndexWriter.java:1930)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.merge.Merges.maybeMerge(Merges.java:47)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.engine.internal.InternalEngine.maybeMerge(InternalEngine.java:926)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.service.InternalIndexShard$EngineMerger$1.run(InternalIndexShard.java:966)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: _7n_es090_0.tim
    at org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory.fileLength(FSDirectory.java:261)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.FilterDirectory.fileLength(FilterDirectory.java:63)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.store.Store$StoreIndexOutput.close(Store.java:611)
    at org.apache.lucene.util.IOUtils.closeWhileHandlingException(IOUtils.java:81)
    at org.apache.lucene.codecs.BlockTreeTermsWriter.close(BlockTreeTermsWriter.java:1140)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.codec.postingsformat.BloomFilterPostingsFormat$BloomFilteredFieldsConsumer.close(BloomFilterPostingsFormat.java:371)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.codec.postingsformat.Elasticsearch090PostingsFormat$1.close(Elasticsearch090PostingsFormat.java:61)
    at org.apache.lucene.codecs.perfield.PerFieldPostingsFormat$FieldsConsumerAndSuffix.close(PerFieldPostingsFormat.java:86)
    at org.apache.lucene.util.IOUtils.close(IOUtils.java:163)
    at org.apache.lucene.codecs.perfield.PerFieldPostingsFormat$FieldsWriter.close(PerFieldPostingsFormat.java:154)
    at org.apache.lucene.util.IOUtils.close(IOUtils.java:140)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentMerger.mergeTerms(SegmentMerger.java:389)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentMerger.merge(SegmentMerger.java:106)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.mergeMiddle(IndexWriter.java:4119)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.merge(IndexWriter.java:3716)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.TrackingSerialMergeScheduler.merge(TrackingSerialMergeScheduler.java:122)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.merge.scheduler.SerialMergeSchedulerProvider$CustomSerialMergeScheduler.merge(SerialMergeSchedulerProvider.java:89)
    ... 9 more
    Suppressed: java.io.FileNotFoundException: _7n_es090_0.tip
        ... 26 more
    Suppressed: java.io.FileNotFoundException: _7n_es090_0.doc
        at org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory.fileLength(FSDirectory.java:261)
        at org.apache.lucene.store.FilterDirectory.fileLength(FilterDirectory.java:63)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.store.Store$StoreIndexOutput.close(Store.java:611)
        at org.apache.lucene.util.IOUtils.close(IOUtils.java:140)
        at org.apache.lucene.codecs.lucene41.Lucene41PostingsWriter.close(Lucene41PostingsWriter.java:587)
        ... 23 more
        Suppressed: java.io.FileNotFoundException: _7n_es090_0.pos
            ... 28 more
[2014-05-01 00:16:49,807][WARN ][index.shard.service      ] [Captain Wings] [index_65][0] Failed to perform scheduled engine optimize/merge
org.elasticsearch.index.engine.OptimizeFailedEngineException: [index_65][0] Optimize failed
    at org.elasticsearch.index.engine.internal.InternalEngine.maybeMerge(InternalEngine.java:936)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.service.InternalIndexShard$EngineMerger$1.run(InternalIndexShard.java:966)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.apache.lucene.index.MergePolicy$MergeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: _7n_es090_0.tim
    at org.elasticsearch.index.merge.scheduler.SerialMergeSchedulerProvider$CustomSerialMergeScheduler.merge(SerialMergeSchedulerProvider.java:93)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.merge.EnableMergeScheduler.merge(EnableMergeScheduler.java:71)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.maybeMerge(IndexWriter.java:1936)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.maybeMerge(IndexWriter.java:1930)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.merge.Merges.maybeMerge(Merges.java:47)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.engine.internal.InternalEngine.maybeMerge(InternalEngine.java:926)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: _7n_es090_0.tim
    at org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory.fileLength(FSDirectory.java:261)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.FilterDirectory.fileLength(FilterDirectory.java:63)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.store.Store$StoreIndexOutput.close(Store.java:611)
    at org.apache.lucene.util.IOUtils.closeWhileHandlingException(IOUtils.java:81)
    at org.apache.lucene.codecs.BlockTreeTermsWriter.close(BlockTreeTermsWriter.java:1140)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.codec.postingsformat.BloomFilterPostingsFormat$BloomFilteredFieldsConsumer.close(BloomFilterPostingsFormat.java:371)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.codec.postingsformat.Elasticsearch090PostingsFormat$1.close(Elasticsearch090PostingsFormat.java:61)
    at org.apache.lucene.codecs.perfield.PerFieldPostingsFormat$FieldsConsumerAndSuffix.close(PerFieldPostingsFormat.java:86)
    at org.apache.lucene.util.IOUtils.close(IOUtils.java:163)
    at org.apache.lucene.codecs.perfield.PerFieldPostingsFormat$FieldsWriter.close(PerFieldPostingsFormat.java:154)
    at org.apache.lucene.util.IOUtils.close(IOUtils.java:140)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentMerger.mergeTerms(SegmentMerger.java:389)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentMerger.merge(SegmentMerger.java:106)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.mergeMiddle(IndexWriter.java:4119)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.merge(IndexWriter.java:3716)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.TrackingSerialMergeScheduler.merge(TrackingSerialMergeScheduler.java:122)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.merge.scheduler.SerialMergeSchedulerProvider$CustomSerialMergeScheduler.merge(SerialMergeSchedulerProvider.java:89)
    ... 9 more
    Suppressed: java.io.FileNotFoundException: _7n_es090_0.tip
        ... 26 more
    Suppressed: java.io.FileNotFoundException: _7n_es090_0.doc
        at org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory.fileLength(FSDirectory.java:261)
        at org.apache.lucene.store.FilterDirectory.fileLength(FilterDirectory.java:63)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.store.Store$StoreIndexOutput.close(Store.java:611)
        at org.apache.lucene.util.IOUtils.close(IOUtils.java:140)
        at org.apache.lucene.codecs.lucene41.Lucene41PostingsWriter.close(Lucene41PostingsWriter.java:587)
        ... 23 more
        Suppressed: java.io.FileNotFoundException: _7n_es090_0.pos
            ... 28 more
[2014-05-01 00:16:49,913][WARN ][cluster.action.shard     ] [Captain Wings] [index_65][0] sending failed shard for [index_65][0], node[Fj243PXdSNGtSm_jLNl9hQ], [P], s[STARTED], indexUUID [v6ZQJKpTRbiZZ5e6Q6ENyw], reason [engine failure, message [MergeException[java.io.FileNotFoundException: _7n_es090_0.tim]; nested: FileNotFoundException[_7n_es090_0.tim]; ]]
[2014-05-01 00:16:49,913][WARN ][cluster.action.shard     ] [Captain Wings] [index_65][0] received shard failed for [index_65][0], node[Fj243PXdSNGtSm_jLNl9hQ], [P], s[STARTED], indexUUID [v6ZQJKpTRbiZZ5e6Q6ENyw], reason [engine failure, message [MergeException[java.io.FileNotFoundException: _7n_es090_0.tim]; nested: FileNotFoundException[_7n_es090_0.tim]; ]]
[2014-05-01 00:17:03,453][WARN ][index.merge.scheduler    ] [Captain Wings] [index_221][0] failed to merge
java.io.FileNotFoundException: _7e_es090_0.tim
    at org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory.fileLength(FSDirectory.java:261)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.FilterDirectory.fileLength(FilterDirectory.java:63)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.store.Store$StoreIndexOutput.close(Store.java:611)
    at org.apache.lucene.util.IOUtils.closeWhileHandlingException(IOUtils.java:81)
    at org.apache.lucene.codecs.BlockTreeTermsWriter.close(BlockTreeTermsWriter.java:1140)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.codec.postingsformat.BloomFilterPostingsFormat$BloomFilteredFieldsConsumer.close(BloomFilterPostingsFormat.java:371)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.codec.postingsformat.Elasticsearch090PostingsFormat$1.close(Elasticsearch090PostingsFormat.java:61)
    at org.apache.lucene.codecs.perfield.PerFieldPostingsFormat$FieldsConsumerAndSuffix.close(PerFieldPostingsFormat.java:86)
    at org.apache.lucene.util.IOUtils.close(IOUtils.java:163)
    at org.apache.lucene.codecs.perfield.PerFieldPostingsFormat$FieldsWriter.close(PerFieldPostingsFormat.java:154)
    at org.apache.lucene.util.IOUtils.close(IOUtils.java:140)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentMerger.mergeTerms(SegmentMerger.java:389)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentMerger.merge(SegmentMerger.java:106)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.mergeMiddle(IndexWriter.java:4119)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.merge(IndexWriter.java:3716)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.TrackingSerialMergeScheduler.merge(TrackingSerialMergeScheduler.java:122)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.merge.scheduler.SerialMergeSchedulerProvider$CustomSerialMergeScheduler.merge(SerialMergeSchedulerProvider.java:89)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.merge.EnableMergeScheduler.merge(EnableMergeScheduler.java:71)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.maybeMerge(IndexWriter.java:1936)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.maybeMerge(IndexWriter.java:1930)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.merge.Merges.maybeMerge(Merges.java:47)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.engine.internal.InternalEngine.maybeMerge(InternalEngine.java:926)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.service.InternalIndexShard$EngineMerger$1.run(InternalIndexShard.java:966)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
    Suppressed: java.io.FileNotFoundException: _7e_es090_0.tip
        ... 26 more
    Suppressed: java.io.FileNotFoundException: _7e_es090_0.doc
        at org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory.fileLength(FSDirectory.java:261)
        at org.apache.lucene.store.FilterDirectory.fileLength(FilterDirectory.java:63)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.store.Store$StoreIndexOutput.close(Store.java:611)
        at org.apache.lucene.util.IOUtils.close(IOUtils.java:140)
        at org.apache.lucene.codecs.lucene41.Lucene41PostingsWriter.close(Lucene41PostingsWriter.java:587)
        ... 23 more
        Suppressed: java.io.FileNotFoundException: _7e_es090_0.pos
            ... 28 more
[2014-05-01 00:17:03,454][WARN ][index.engine.internal    ] [Captain Wings] [index_221][0] failed engine
org.apache.lucene.index.MergePolicy$MergeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: _7e_es090_0.tim
    at org.elasticsearch.index.merge.scheduler.SerialMergeSchedulerProvider$CustomSerialMergeScheduler.merge(SerialMergeSchedulerProvider.java:92)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.merge.EnableMergeScheduler.merge(EnableMergeScheduler.java:71)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.maybeMerge(IndexWriter.java:1936)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.maybeMerge(IndexWriter.java:1930)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.merge.Merges.maybeMerge(Merges.java:47)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.engine.internal.InternalEngine.maybeMerge(InternalEngine.java:926)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.service.InternalIndexShard$EngineMerger$1.run(InternalIndexShard.java:966)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: _7e_es090_0.tim
    at org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory.fileLength(FSDirectory.java:261)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.FilterDirectory.fileLength(FilterDirectory.java:63)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.store.Store$StoreIndexOutput.close(Store.java:611)
    at org.apache.lucene.util.IOUtils.closeWhileHandlingException(IOUtils.java:81)
    at org.apache.lucene.codecs.BlockTreeTermsWriter.close(BlockTreeTermsWriter.java:1140)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.codec.postingsformat.BloomFilterPostingsFormat$BloomFilteredFieldsConsumer.close(BloomFilterPostingsFormat.java:371)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.codec.postingsformat.Elasticsearch090PostingsFormat$1.close(Elasticsearch090PostingsFormat.java:61)
    at org.apache.lucene.codecs.perfield.PerFieldPostingsFormat$FieldsConsumerAndSuffix.close(PerFieldPostingsFormat.java:86)
    at org.apache.lucene.util.IOUtils.close(IOUtils.java:163)
    at org.apache.lucene.codecs.perfield.PerFieldPostingsFormat$FieldsWriter.close(PerFieldPostingsFormat.java:154)
    at org.apache.lucene.util.IOUtils.close(IOUtils.java:140)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentMerger.mergeTerms(SegmentMerger.java:389)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentMerger.merge(SegmentMerger.java:106)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.mergeMiddle(IndexWriter.java:4119)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.merge(IndexWriter.java:3716)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.TrackingSerialMergeScheduler.merge(TrackingSerialMergeScheduler.java:122)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.merge.scheduler.SerialMergeSchedulerProvider$CustomSerialMergeScheduler.merge(SerialMergeSchedulerProvider.java:89)
    ... 9 more
    Suppressed: java.io.FileNotFoundException: _7e_es090_0.tip
        ... 26 more
    Suppressed: java.io.FileNotFoundException: _7e_es090_0.doc
        at org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory.fileLength(FSDirectory.java:261)
        at org.apache.lucene.store.FilterDirectory.fileLength(FilterDirectory.java:63)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.store.Store$StoreIndexOutput.close(Store.java:611)
        at org.apache.lucene.util.IOUtils.close(IOUtils.java:140)
        at org.apache.lucene.codecs.lucene41.Lucene41PostingsWriter.close(Lucene41PostingsWriter.java:587)
        ... 23 more
        Suppressed: java.io.FileNotFoundException: _7e_es090_0.pos
            ... 28 more
[2014-05-01 00:17:06,961][INFO ][node                     ] [Captain Wings] stopped
[2014-05-01 00:17:06,961][INFO ][node                     ] [Captain Wings] closing ...
[2014-05-01 00:17:06,966][INFO ][node                     ] [Captain Wings] closed
```

EDIT: another run to store 3m documents over 100 indexes. Here is a screenshot from BigDesk I took when ES crashed:
[image: BigDesk Capture]

Here is the stacktrace (used an external repo since it was too big to paste)
http://m.uploadedit.com/b034/1399053538319.txt

It stopped at ~500k docs, I was checking the files descriptors open for that process and they were < 5000. Heap memory for the JVM -Xmx is 20gb and 5 shards...

Anyway, storing 3m docs in 1 index is simply fine.

EDIT:
ulimit -a output:

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 240150
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 1024
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

The number of files has been changed inside the /etc/security/limits.conf file, to 64000. It does not display here. I was monitoring the number of open files inside the /proc//fd/ folder, it was beyond 1024 (I think was around 6k for 100 indexes) but well below 64k.

EDIT:
Result of `http://54.227.158.137:9200/_nodes/stats/indices?pretty` before a crash:

`{
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "nodes" : {
    "t5FjNo1xQbCk97Qqv0w2sQ" : {
      "timestamp" : 1399395162423,
      "name" : "Dementia",
      "transport_address" : "inet[/10.69.21.196:9300]",
      "host" : "ip-10-69-21-196",
      "ip" : [ "inet[/10.69.21.196:9300]", "NONE" ],
      "indices" : {
        "docs" : {
          "count" : 433533,
          "deleted" : 0
        },
        "store" : {
          "size_in_bytes" : 10837028821,
          "throttle_time_in_millis" : 1971123
        },
        "indexing" : {
          "index_total" : 435229,
          "index_time_in_millis" : 1651288,
          "index_current" : 0,
          "delete_total" : 0,
          "delete_time_in_millis" : 0,
          "delete_current" : 0
        },
        [...]
        "merges" : {
          "current" : 4,
          "current_docs" : 574,
          "current_size_in_bytes" : 10968915,
          "total" : 13935,
          "total_time_in_millis" : 9056598,
          "total_docs" : 635889,
          "total_size_in_bytes" : 15384667490
        },
        "refresh" : {
          "total" : 161452,
          "total_time_in_millis" : 9013814
        },
        "flush" : {
          "total" : 1000,
          "total_time_in_millis" : 730342
        },
        "warmer" : {
          "current" : 0,
          "total" : 176035,
          "total_time_in_millis" : 18410
        },
        "filter_cache" : {
          "memory_size_in_bytes" : 0,
          "evictions" : 0
        },
        "id_cache" : {
          "memory_size_in_bytes" : 0
        },
        "fielddata" : {
          "memory_size_in_bytes" : 0,
          "evictions" : 0
        },
        "percolate" : {
          "total" : 0,
          "time_in_millis" : 0,
          "current" : 0,
          "memory_size_in_bytes" : -1,
          "memory_size" : "-1b",
          "queries" : 0
        },
        "completion" : {
          "size_in_bytes" : 0
        },
        "segments" : {
          "count" : 36091,
          "memory_in_bytes" : 76230702
        },
        "translog" : {
          "operations" : 80160,
          "size_in_bytes" : 1070283
        }
      }
    }
  }
}`

Comment: Would help a lot if you could post the memory error you are receiving along with stack trace -

Comment: Sorry, added the stack trace from ES log.. Once that happens, ES simply crashes and the python script gives a ConnectionError Exception (because it cannot find the search engine any longer..)

Comment: Did you up the number of file descriptors (since you are seeing file not found, you might be running out) -- see http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup-configuration.html

Comment: @Alcanzar, yes, I changed it to 64k.

Comment: These look like low level file errors to me. What kind of file system are you storing your indexes on? Local drive, network, nfs?

Comment: The files are stored on my local system.

Comment: I've edited the post and added another test run from this morning. It fails storing over 100 indexes..

Comment: ulimit -a output?  Sometimes failure to create a new thread shows up as OOM.

Comment: @Alcanzar: I've appended the ulimit -a output to the post.

Comment: Anyway I was monitoring the number of es threads and it is always around 80~120 regardless of the number of indexes.

Comment: Look at your ulimit output.. your open files is 1024.  Your change to 64K didn't work.

Comment: It actually does.. if you check the settings retrieved with the /_nodes/settings?pretty command, the result is: ` "process" : { 
        "refresh_interval" : 1000, 
        "id" : 20155, 
        "max_file_descriptors" : 64000, 
        "mlockall" : false 
      }, `

Comment: I monitored the number of open files in the /proc/xxx/fd/ and it was beyond 1024 but way less then 64k..

Comment: The one thing I still see is that you are running a version of 1.7 JVM that isn't officially listed as working by ES.  1.7u55 is the official version that works.  In the ES training class I took there was some mention of an index corrupting bug in one of the late 1.7 java releases that's fixed in u55... so might try that change.

Comment: Cool, I'll try that in the weekend. Now I'm running another extensive test and it will keep the machine busy for another 6-8 hrs..

Comment: Hello @Alcanzar, no luck with java1.7.0_u55, the latest one. I guess I'll need to change my approach to 1 big index... although this defeats my initial index-isolation idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tuned your field data cache? It defaults to unbounded and with this many indexes it is not surprising that you run out of memory. http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-fielddata.html

Update, this apparently solved the problem:

The OOM is happening with memory mapped files. This type of memory is allocated outside of the regular JVM heap and is also out of scope for garbage collections. Have a look at this thread: [groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/elasticsearch/4Nj_HUl78KA](http://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/elasticsearch/4Nj_HUl78KA) for some things that might work. Apparently linux limits memory available for this by default and you should be able to remove this restriction.

Comment: I remember i tried to set the indices.fielddata.cache.size: 30% with no luck.. Is that what you mean?

Comment: I've added the result from '_nodes/stats/indices?pretty` before a crash, cousl it be useful?

Comment: yes 30% would be about right. I just looked through your stack trace; no mention of out of memory exceptions there but plenty of scary file not found exceptions. Something is very wrong with your setup. If you run out of memory, you should be seeing OOM exceptions in the log at least. As noted above, the log is saying that it can't find a lot of files and then decides to shut down the node. Might be a permissions problem or maybe something is wrong with your storage setup or indeed the number of filehandles. Whatever it is, you are not running out of memory here.

Comment: Did you check also the link? Theres another stacktrace there.. The indexing is doing fine till a certain point and then it bombs.. So i dont think its a matter of permission.. I run everything as root and the data folder is writeable.

Comment: Missed that link indeed. The OOM is happening with memory mapped files. This type of memory is allocated outside of the regular JVM heap and is also out of scope for garbage collections. Have a look at this thread: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/elasticsearch/4Nj_HUl78KA for some things that might work. Apparently linux limits memory available for this by default and you should be able to remove this restriction.

Comment: Thank you for the insight! Now I'm involved in another part of the project and I cannot perform the test but when I'm going back to ES I'll try this thing and let you know.

Comment: It worked!! Put your comment as an answer so I can accept it! If you could elaborate a bit more on the answer that'd be cool! 

I transferred 2000 indexes and 200mil documents without any problems!

Comment: The Elasticsearch Google group has migrated to Elasticsearch's own forum. I think the thread/post in question must be this one: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/what-os-memory-does-es-use-other-than-java/17379/2